# swift PFQueryTableViewController - remove duplicate objects before presenting cells

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I have two Classes in Parse, one contains details of images that users have liked ("Liked"), the second class lists users that are following other users ("Follows").

In my `PFQueryViewController` I am able to create a query in `queryForTable()`  that does the following:

```
    //get username of users being followed
    let query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className:"Follows")
    query.whereKey("fromUser", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)

    //get images of all followed users
    let imageQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Liked")
    imageQuery.whereKey("username", matchesKey: "toUser", inQuery: query)

    //get images current user liked
    let userImagesQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Liked")
    userImagesQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)

    //combine liked images of following and current user
    let combinedQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([imageQuery,userImagesQuery])


    if(objects?.count == 0)
    {
        combinedQuery.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheThenNetwork
    }

    combinedQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")


    return combinedQuery
```

This works where I am able to display the liked images of the user, and the users being followed, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` by querying the `imageID` of the object for each cell. However, multiple users can like the same image, so if a user and someone they are following like the same image, the image will appear twice in the table.

Is there a way to force the query to ignore objects when it finds a duplicate based on the `ImageID` key?

I am aware this can be done by executing the query and iterating through the objects, however this wont work in this scenario as I need the duplicates to be removed before the query is returned in `queryForTable()`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by using objectsDidLoad(). This captures the objects before they are sent to the table, therefore I was able to iterate through each object and delete any duplicates.

I store all the loaded objects into a new array and remove an object if a duplicate is found. I then make the object in cellForRowAtIndexPath the corresponding object in the array.

```
 override func objectsDidLoad(error: NSError?) {
    super.objectsDidLoad(error)

    displayedImages.removeAll()
    imageObjects = NSMutableArray(array: objects!)

    for item in imageObjects {
        if displayedImages.count == 0 {
            let image = item["imageid"] as! NSNumber
            displayedImages.insert(image, atIndex: 0)
        }else{
            var count = 0
            let image = item["imageid"] as! NSNumber
            for imageToCheck in displayedImages {
                if imageToCheck != image {
                    count++
                }
            }
            if count != displayedImages.count {
                imageObjects.removeObject(item)
            }else{
                displayedImages.insert(image, atIndex: 0)
            }
        }
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return imageObjects.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! FeedTableViewCell

     if let pfObject:PFObject = self.imageObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? PFObject {

//display images as before
```